# Can a link to the glossary be added to the SO faq page?

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request, glossary

So today I was wondering what the meaning of the term `score` was as relating to questions and answers and had to look it up in Meta Stackoverflow only to find that there was a [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Could it be possible to add a link to the glossary to the main site either in the `faq` or on the main menu with the rest of the areas like `chat meta about faq`?

Comment: It's already in the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) which is the central faq page: *To see a list of commonly used words and phrases, see the [glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)*

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) not the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @Ben yep, got it too and edited the tags accordingly. :)

Comment: Exactly @Ben I am referring to the Faq of SO not Meta SO or any other SE site including the main SE site. Not everyone uses that site. I started with SO and it is where I go mostly although I do have a few other SE accounts, when I'm working in SO I want to find information on SO not have to bounce around several sites looking for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the glossary deserves to be in the main [faq page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

However, the glossary is mentioned in the [central faq page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) here on Meta so instead of just linking to all questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on Meta, I would change the link in the following faq paragraph (the part in bold) to point on that central faq page.

> ### What if I need more help?
>
> If you’re looking for excruciating detail, our meta-discussion site hosts a section of constantly evolving **frequently asked questions** that document everything about the site. Or, maybe you’d just like to learn a little more about us?

This way it would be much easier to navigate through the different faq's available, and the glossary get place of honor on top.